# Get firefox profile path in selenium WebdriverJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-driver

How can I access/get the firefox profile path, from [welenium webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium)?

I can't seem to find it in the docs here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_Capabilities.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey so to get the profile what I ended up doing is the following:

```
let capabilities = await this.firefox.getCapabilities();
let profile = capabilities.get('moz:profile');
```

Then you have access to the temporal profile.